# Question about MySql index and Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, mysql, indexing

In Asp.net C# I use the following code to select from a MySql-database:

```
string userid = "12";
MySqlCommand mysqlcmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT productid FROM table WHERE userid=?userid", mysqlconn);
mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?userid", userid);
mysqlcmd.Connection.Open();
mysqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
...
```

In the table the userid is of the type int. If I have an index in the table on userid what will happen with this query, will it be able to use the index in a good way even if the userid I add to the parameter is a string and the index in the table is int?

Would it give me better performance to before adding userid to the parameter convert userid to an int like this:

```
int userid_int = Int32.Parse(userid);
MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter("?userid", MySqlDbType.Int32);
param.Value = userid_int;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Or is it ok to only use:

```
mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?userid", userid);
```

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823674/sql-net-sqlparameters-addwithvalue-are-there-any-negative-performance-im

Comment: @The Scrum Meister So from what I understand it is ok to use AddWithValue() as this set the right paramter type for me automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are used no matter what kind of datatype the indexed column is. The questions is, how efficient this will happen.

For instance, if you use string-columns with indexes for search you should ensure, that the values in that columns are differing from each other. If you have records like

```
index_column
------------
DHDHDSNDH233
DHDHDSNDH234
DHDHDSNDH235
DHDHDSNDH236
```

the index is a little bit useless because the engine has to load a lot of data for finding your keys.

This is the reason why a lot of people are using GUIDs when search-indexing a string-column.

If the column is'nt the PK, you have to live with that possible bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure I understand. I updated the question to make my question more clear. Can you take a look at it again?

Comment: @Martin Oh sorry. IMHO both are ok because the usage of indexes is decided not by the framework but by the dbms. So if the type does not match to Int32 it'll raise an exception but this has nothing to do with indexes. This is just clean programming.